Multiple Link-local (zeroconf) network on Ubuntu won't work
I have an Ubuntu machine, with two wired networks: enp2s0 and enp3s0. They connect to two different Local networks. One of the networks has a Raspi, and another one has a Windows machine.
The IP addresses are:
pi 169.254.152.68
enp2s0: 169.254.249.122
enp3s0: 169.254.130.11
windows: 169.254.188.37

The problem is when I connect both of them, the network will stop working at one side, depending on how I plug them in.
One example:
If I plug enp2s0 first, then plug enp3s0, Windows will not be able to ping Ubuntu, the same as Ubuntu to Windows, but Pi is able to ping the two link-local addresses on Ubuntu, even though the enp3s0 cannot be seen by the Pi.
Ubuntu version is 23.04 and kernel is 6.2.0-39-generic
Below is the network connection diagram.


Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.
